# Convert a SQL query to lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    M.MailItemId, m.Subject,
    ISNULL(m.SendCC, ''),
    ISNULL(attachments.counter, 0) Counters,
    M.CreationDate 
FROM
    MailItem AS M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         MailItemId, COUNT(MailItemId) counter 
     FROM Attachment Group By MailItemId) AS attachments ON M.MailItemId = attachments.MailItemId
```

There are two models `MailItem` and `Attachment`. wants to fetch data based on above conditions.

I want to convert above query to a lambda expression.

Comment: **Lambda** - not "lambada" ....

Comment: Please add you entites, code you have tried and what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your entity models look like this requires a lot of assumptions, mainly with the existence of a navigation property `Attachments` that defines the one-to-many relationship between `MailItem` and `Attachment`. But assuming it does exist you should be able to do something as simple as:

```
_context.MailItems.Select(mi => new {
    MailItemId = mi.MailItemId,
    Subject = mi.Subject,
    Subject = mi.SendCC,
    Counters = mi.Attachments.Count,
    CreationDate  = mi.CreationDate 
});
```

Comment: @stickt01 MailItemId is primary key from MailItem table and which is foriegn key in Attachment table.

Comment: Sure @Kida - so typically your `MaiItem` model will have a property like `public virtual IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments` and `Attachment` will have a property of `public virtual MailItem MailItem`. The foreign key relationship will then often be defined using these navigation properties in a mapping file. Although this assumes code-first...as with so much of this without seeing your models it is almost impossible to construct an expression.

Comment: @stickt01- No. MailItem and Attachment are two different models.Both are having MailItemId property.

Comment: Yes I understand that @Kida but navigation properties can make generating queries like the one you want much easier. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships).